# How to dynamically set center of Map : Openstreetmap

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap

I'm using openstreetmap and can't set the center of the map dynamically.

Below is my code.

```
function Map({ locations }) {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={
        locations.length > 0 && [parseFloat(locations[0].long), parseFloat(locations[0].lang)]
      }
      zoom={15}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {locations.length &&
        locations.map((lo) => (
          <Marker key={lo.locationId} position={[lo.long, lo.lang]}>
            <Popup>text</Popup>
          </Marker>
        ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Example `locations` array:

```
[{locationId: 1, name: 'aa', long: '111.000', lang: '125.00'}, ...]
```

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
    at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:22:1)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:28:1)
    at NewClass.project (Map.js:980:1)
    at NewClass._getNewPixelOrigin (Map.js:1503:1)
    at NewClass._move (Map.js:1222:1)
    at NewClass._resetView (Map.js:1182:1)
    at NewClass.setView (Map.js:206:1)
    at MapContainer.js:32:1
    at commitAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:23645:1)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23503:1)
```

Other Ways:
I tried below:

```
let long, lang;
  if (locations.length > 0) {
    long = parseFloat(locations[0]?.long);
    lang = parseFloat(locations[0]?.lang);

    console.log(typeof [long, lang]); // prints -> Object
    console.log([long, lang]); // prints -> [111.00, 233.00] // gets data
  }
```

and I use `long` and `lang` in `center` props like `center={[long, lang]}`. But same error.

I'm using react and react-leaflet.

Comment: Can you provide example of locations array.

Comment: @BK52 I've updated.

Comment: I reproduced your code in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-worker-3zp49c?file=/src/App.js). I didn't get any error.

Comment: But if I don't send second parameter to the MapContainer.center, I get an error 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')'.

Comment: So be sure your locations array is correct. With console.log(locations) check your lang value

Comment: And I see <Marker key={lo.loId} but in your array this field is 'locationId'.

Comment: works with my solution? (because I can't still access your link)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-worker-3zp49c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: updated queston.

Comment: Did you use console.log(locations) and see the result in Map component?

Comment: Yes. They exist perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from the definition of center

```
function Map({ locations }) {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={
        ( locations && locations.length > 0 ) ? 
         [parseFloat(locations[0].long), parseFloat(locations[0].lang)]
         : 
         [0, 0]}
      zoom={15}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {locations.length &&
        locations.map((lo) => (
          <Marker key={lo.locationId} position={[lo.long, lo.lang]}>
            <Popup>text</Popup>
          </Marker>
        ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

With the way you did `locations.length > 0 && ...`  it can put a false instead of an interpretable center like `[0, 0]`

Comment: It always set [0, 0].

Comment: updated queston.

Comment: @Ms.Siri It means that ```( locations && locations.length > 0 )``` is always interpreted as ```false```, which means your problem comes from the definition of locations. As stated in your question it should work properly. I mean if location is defined and its length is not zero, ```( locations && locations.length > 0 )``` should be true.

Comment: Yes. That's why I feel strange. If I set to center [0, 0], then it doesn't produce the error I mentioned in my question..... And I can see those markers components in the map according to the `locations` data. But If I changed to dynamic center values `[lang, long]`, the error occurs and nothing is rendered.

Comment: Moreover, if location is shown as defined, it could mean that the problem comes from the life cycle of your component. I mean, if it is rendered with ```locations = undefined``` and that changes in locations does not trigger a rerender, your are left with an outdated component

Comment: Ah ok, I dont know why but I have the intuition that the problem comes from the lifecycle, if MapContainer uses the center props when it renders (which I think it does because you can change the center by moving the map) then, if it renders without props at first (even 1ms) then the component already have a center defined and does not change it, unlike positions that can appear afterwards

Comment: If so, there might not be a way to set the center from the start?

Comment: To test this hypothesis, you should use a state or ref for the center and trigger a forced rerender once it is setted to the desired value.